# Relate channel entries to members?

Tags: members, relationships, related

Can you relate channel entries to members?

I need to be able to create a channel into which entries are posted and a relationship field is shown so that I can select a member that the entry pertains to.

I want to then use this relationship to show these entries to those logged in members on the front end of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I knew somebody had to have done this already.
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-list-custom-field

Comment: This would be perfect... if it was for EE3 :(   Turns out there is a feature that lets you include members in the author list so I could set the author and then filter by author_id on the front end template but I feel this isn't as ideal a solution as I'd like. I may end up going with a paid for solution like Solspace User as this appears to have this capacity?..